# Create multiple copies of the same file using CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way of making about 10 copies of "final.txt" with the name "final2.txt"?

Example of folder:

> final.txt final2.txt final3.txt final4.txt final5.txt final6.txt
> final7.txt final8.txt final9.txt final10.txt

I want to use *wildcards* and **I'd like to refrain from FOR loops.**

If a FOR loop is really necessary, then that's okay.

Comment: with DOS, your possibilities are quite limited. Do you REALLY mean DOS rather than Windows `cmd`?

Comment: I meant cmd.... Excuse my stupidity

Comment: don't mind. That's a common mistake. But we need to know, because there are huge differences in functionality between DOS and CMD.

Comment: Excuse me. A _Wildcard_ is used to select several _existent_ files with similar names. If you want to copy just _one file_ (named "file.txt") then there is not any Wildcard (`*` or `?` character) here!

Comment: Re *"...with the name "final2.txt""*: Don't you mean with an incrementing number, "final2.txt", "final3.txt", "final4.txt", etc.?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 5):

a `for` loop is the easiest of all things:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do copy final.txt final%%i.txt
```

If it has to be without `for`:

```
set Count=0
:Loop
set /a Count+=1
copy file.txt file%count%.txt
if %Count% lss 10 goto :loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set pathtofile="" 



for %%f in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (

    type NUL > %pathtofile%\textfile_%%f.txt

)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You are a life saver! :)

Comment: No Problem. If you run into a problem and it says "Cannot find specified path" or "Access is Denied". Just plug in the path in the for loop rather than a variable.

Comment: just to mention: this doesn't make ten copies of a file, but creates ten empty files.